# Getting callback results to send to AJAX from php and update table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, callback

I am updating a database table via AJAX and PHP right now, but I want my page to be more responsive and update my table in my file after the data has been inserted into the database table.

I am not sure how to send info from my php file to AJAX and then how to get AJAX to update the table. How can I call back the data from my PHP file in order to make my table interactive?

The table

```
    Current Announcements
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Username</th>
                <th>Message</th>
                <th>Date</th>
            </tr>   
<?php
        while ($row = $announcements_stmt->fetch()) {
?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $announcements_id; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $announcements_username; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $announcements_messages; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $announcements_date; ?></td>
                </tr>   

<?php
        } 
?>

    }
            </table>
<?php           
    }
}
```

AJAX

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
         $("#submit_announcement").on("click", function () {

         var user_message = $("#announcement_message").val();
            //$user = this.value;
             $user = $("#approved_id").val();
            $.ajax({ 
                url: "insert_announcements.php", 
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                       "user_id": $user,
                                    //"message": user_message
                                    "user_message": user_message
                        },
                success: function (data) {
                       //  console.log(data); // data object will return the response when status code is 200
                         if (data == "Error!") {
                             alert("Unable to get user info!");
                             alert(data);
                         } else {
                             $(".announcement_success").fadeIn();
                             $(".announcement_success").show();
                             $('.announcement_success').html('Announcement Successfully Added!');
                             $('.announcement_success').delay(5000).fadeOut(400);
                         }
                     },
                     error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                         alert(textStatus + "|" + errorThrown);
                         //console.log("error"); //otherwise error if status code is other than 200.
                     }
                 });
             });
         });
```

PHP file

```
$announcement_user_id= $_POST['user_id'];
$announcement_message= $_POST['user_message'];
$test = print_r($_POST, true); 
file_put_contents('test.txt', $test); 
//var_dump($announcement_user_id);

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "", "", "");
$stmt2 = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO announcements (user_id, message, date) VALUES (?, ?, NOW())");
    if ( !$stmt2 || $con->error ) {
        // Check Errors for prepare
         die('Announcement INSERT prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($con->error));
    }
    if(!$stmt2->bind_param('is', $announcement_user_id, $announcement_message)) {
        // Check errors for binding parameters
        die('Announcement INSERT bind_param() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt2->error));
    }
    if(!$stmt2->execute()) {
        die('Announcement INSERT execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt2->error));
    }
        //echo "Announcement was added successfully!";
    else
    {
         echo "Announcement Failed!";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think to do this, the following steps is what you need:

- Write a new php script that gets the items form the database (like in 'the table' script) and echo these items in the table format you want. So when you call this script, it echo's only a table containing the rows.
- Remove the dynamic rows part from the 'the table' script.
- On success of your ajax request, make a new request to the new php script
- Place the output of that script in the html using jQuery (.html(), insertAfter(), appendTo(), or anything like that).

`